# How to remove files from directory with certain extenions using command line in linux

Tags: r, linux

I'm trying to use a system command in R to remove all files from a directory that have an extension of either `.html` or `.png`

I can remove files with one given extension type for example like:

```
system("rm -f ~/folder_path/*.html")
```

But I can't figure out how to remove files with one extension type or another. I have tried:

```
system("rm -f ~/folder_path/\\(*.html|*.png\\)")
```

But this errors with `sh: 1: *.png): not found`

R session information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 RC (2015-06-10 r68509)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
files_to_remove <- list.files(pattern=".html|.png", full.name=T)
file.remove(files_to_remove)
```

Try not to write system-specific code and look at `?file`.

Comment: sure will do, but I have to wait 3mins :)

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a simple way to do this using the rm command.

```
system("rm DIRECTORY/*.html;rm DIRECTORY/*.png")
```

Replace DIRECTORY with the name of your directory. This should remove all htmls and pngs from the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple command

```
rm -rf /directory/*.file type
```

rm: for the rm gernal command
-rf: for the remove all file forcefully
*: for all files
*.filetype: for all file extension like HTML, png, pdf etc

Real-world example:
remove all pdf file from /home use this command:

```
rm -rf /home/*.pdf
```